# Problems with windows service, blockingcollection, and Multithreading

Tags: .net, multithreading, exception, windows-services, task-parallel-library

My scenario:

- Windows Service .NET 4
- I poll a database for entities.
- When new entities come in they are added to a `BlockingCollection`.
- In the service's `OnStart` I create a `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` whose job is to enumerate the `BlockingCollection` (using `GetConsumingEnumerable()`).

The problem I'm having is this:

- When an unhandled exception occurs in the task, I want the exception logged and the service stopped.
- I can't catch exceptions from the task unless I call `Task.Wait()`.
- If I call `Task.Wait()` the `OnStart` method blocks and the service never finishes starting.

So how can I make this work?

Comment: Can't you catch all exceptions in the Task body and handle them as appropriate?

Comment: It's not possible to handle something that you don't expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can handle exceptions in a task using the `.ContinueWith' method:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {

    // Do some long action
    Thread.SpinWait(5000000);

    // that eventually has an error :-(
    throw new Exception("Something really bad happened in the task.");

    // I'm not sure how much `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` helps, but it sounds 
    // like it makes sense to use it in your situation.
}, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning).ContinueWith(task => {

    var exception = task.Exception;

    /* Log the exception */

}, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted); // Only run the continuation if there was an error in the original task.
```

Comment: Note for newbies trying the above code sample in a prototype application: Create the task using a variable- ` Task myTask = <the code as above>; myTask.Wait();` The myTask.Wait() would cause the main thread to wait on the task created so that you may see the above in action