# Handling multi-threading using TPL in windows service (conception)

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have a vb.net service that needs some threads to handle each function call separately and avoid time consumption.

I have 2 functions that needs to implement threads :

Before asking my questions, here's my two functions :

1- LaunchTasks() : If the task is well launched it calculates the 'NextRunDate' for this task otherwise it skips it.

```
'Dim oThread As Threading.Thread
For Each oRow As DataRow In oDatatable.Rows
    Dim oCLASSE_Task As New CLASSE_Task
    If oCLASSE_Task.Load(oRow.Item("Mytask")) Then

        'oThread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf oTask.launchSteps)
        'oThread.Priority = Threading.ThreadPriority.Normal
        'oThread.Start()

        Dim oThread = System.Threading.Tasks.Task(Of Boolean).Factory.StartNew(Function() oCLASSE_Task.launchSteps())

    End If
Next
' Need to wait until all threads finish
```

2- calculateRunDates()

```
'It's called for each object in CLASSE_Task

'Dim oThread As Threading.Thread
For Each oRow As DataRow In oDatatable.Rows
    Dim oCLASSE_Task As New CLASSE_Task
    If oCLASSE_Task.Load(oRow.Item("Mytask")) Then

        Dim oThreadTask = System.Threading.Tasks.Task(Of Boolean).Factory.StartNew(Function() oCLASSE_Task.calculateNextRunDate())

        'oThread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf oTask.calculateNextRunDate)
        'oThread.Priority = Threading.ThreadPriority.Normal
        'oThread.Start()

    End If
Next
' Need to wait until all threads finish
```

I always call LaunchTask() first and then calculateRunDates() (if I get new record in the database).

I must wait for all the threads in the function LaunchTask() to finish before I start the calculateRunDates().

- How can I do this using TPL (I never used it before), something like thread.join()?
- Should I use threads or TPL in this situation?
- How Can I handle exception using TPL, in a service (somthing like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770291/problems-with-windows-service-blockingcollection-and-multithreading-tpl))?

Note: I have locks in my CLASSE_Task using SyncLock.

There is not enough examples using vb.net, mostly C#.

Hope that I was clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, to answer your questions:

> How can I do this using TPL (I never used it before), something like thread.join()?

You should use [`task.Wait()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235635) for that. If you wanted to wait for several `Task`s, you can use [`Task.WaitAll()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695.aspx).

> Should I use threads or TPL in this situation?

You should use TPL. It's easier to use and more efficient.

> How can I handle exception using TPL, in a service?

If the code inside a `Task` throws an exception and you then `Wait()` on that `Task` (or `WaitAll()` on multiple `Task`s), it will throw `AggregateException` containing the thrown exception. If you don't call `Wait()`, you can use `ContinueWith()`, as the question you linked to suggests.

---

But with your code, I think a better choice would be to use [`Parallel.ForEach()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx): it will take care of creating the `Task`s for you, it will do it more efficiently (it shares `Task`s between iterations) and you don't have to handle waiting, because when it returns, all iteration is complete:

```
Parallel.ForEach(oDatatable.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow)(),
                 Sub(oRow)
                     Dim oCLASSE_Task As New CLASSE_Task
                     If oCLASSE_Task.Load(oRow.Item("Mytask")) Then
                         oCLASSE_Task.launchSteps()
                     End If
                 End Sub)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try to run and test my program with following code !

Comment: Sometimes, it jumps over some records. Some records are not updated or not recorded. Do you have any idea ? I can't even debug. There is a way to debug ?

Comment: You should be able to debug normally. Breakpoints should work just fine.

Comment: In fact, when I use breakpoints, it breaks and the records are saved correctly. But when I do not put Breakpoints, it just jumps over some functions inside the launchSteps() or calculateNextRunDate() and records are not saved in the database. There is a something that I must add to handle database records ?

Answer (score 1):

To wait for completion of multiple task you can use Task.WaitAll(...) method. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695.aspx) for an example. 
The article also shows how to handle exceptions if any were thrown by the tasks. Put try/catch around Task.WaitAll() and inspect the caught AggregateException to get individual exceptions thrown by the tasks.

However, it looks like your code would benefint from using Parallel.ForEach API, which will provide more intelligent loop partition. Simply creating a separate Task for each row may overload the thread pool.

Comment: What Parallel.ForEach will do for you, it will try to create optimal number of concurrent Tasks to work on the loop. This number will be close to the number of CPU cores on your machine. This is better than just creating one Task per each DataRow, because it reduces context switches and doesn't create much more threads than can possibly run concurrently on your machine.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I will use Parallel.ForEach(), it seems better for my case.

Comment: @Volma Using many `Task`s most likely won't create many threads, so it won't cause context switches. But you are right that it is less efficient than using `Parallel.ForEach()`.

Comment: @svick Why not? The number of threads and the rate of their creation will be controlled by the thread pool, but it will most likelly be much larger than with Parallel.ForEach()

Comment: @Volma Not really. With `Parallel.ForEach()`, the number of threads used is also controlled by the `ThreadPool` (unless you explicitly set a maximum), so the same rules apply.

Comment: ForEach contains additional logic on top of ThreadPool throttling as far as I know. See this for example: [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114317/does-parallel-foreach-limits-the-number-of-active-threads